# Change the folder of recording in Windows 10 Xbox app

Tags: windows-10, recording, xbox-video

Is there any way to change the recording folder for xbox app in windows 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xbox App seems to save recordings into a folder called "Capture" in your videos library folder. Change the location of your Videos folder and it will still save into that folder just in the new location